# Shopify GraphQl Mutation getting an error when sending DraftOrderSendInvoice

Tags: javascript, graphql, shopify, react-apollo

I am creating a Draft Order and everything is working fine, But I am getting a GID which is not working when I am trying to send DraftOrderInvoice. I am not sure if the if my format is wrong or maybe I missed something, but any help in directions is much appreciated.

Let me know if any additional information is needed to clarify the current question.

```
mutation draftOrderCreate($input: DraftOrderInput!) {
  draftOrderCreate(input: $input) {
    draftOrder {
      id
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

After the Draft order is created. I recieve a response with the GID "gid://shopify/DraftOrder/xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

I am then using the Draft Order Id to send an invoice, but I am having some formatting issues I think.

I plugged the Gid into the "Shopify GraphiQL App" to test for mutations and I get an error with the draft order Id.

```
mutation draftOrderInvoiceSend($id: ID!) {
  draftOrderInvoiceSend(id: $id) {
    draftOrder {
      id
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Variable

```
{
  "id": "gid://shopify/DraftOrder/xxxxxxxxxx"  
}
```

​
Error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Internal error. Looks like something went wrong on our end.\nRequest ID: ff0c8cfd-ce93-446f-9f12-b09580f945b7 (include this in support requests)."
    }
  ]
}
```

According to Shopify Mutations the ID should look similar to the obj below
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/mutation/draftorderinvoicesend

```
{
  "id": "Z2lkOi8vU2hvcGlmeS9FeGFtcGxlLzE="
}
```